# deserializing JSON to .net object using NewtonSoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft's JSON Parser.

i obtain json in response. and each time it may be different. Possible variants:
1.

```
[
       {
        "type": "typing",
           "updates": [
               {
                   "__type": "qwerty"
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

2.

```
[ 
    {
        "token": 1111,
        "type": "msg",
        "updates": [           
            {
                "__type": "asdfg",
                ....
            },
            {
                "__type": "asdfg",
                ....
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "typing",
        "updates": [
            {
                "__type": "qwerty"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The question is, what structure my object should have to parse any type of json?

```
var jToken = JToken.Parse(myResponse);
var obj = jToken.ToObject<MyObject>();

class MyObject
{
// what structure should i have here?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

they are not different objects. Your service returns an object array where each object contains an "updates" array

```
var myobj =   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject[]>(json);

public class MyObject
{
    public string token;
    public string type;
    public Update[] updates;
}
public class Update
{
    public string __type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into one of the built in JSON serializors for .NET.

One (The better of the two) is found in [System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)

The other is in
[System.Web.Script.Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx) is a detailed description of how to use `DataContractJsonSerializer`.